# Use of limits to prove $\frac{(m+1)}{m}<\log(m)$ for sufficiently large $m$

Tags: calculus, inequality

For sufficiently large integer $m$, in order to prove

$\frac{(m+1)}{m}<\log(m)$

is it sufficient to point out that

$ \displaystyle\lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{(m+1)}{m}=1 $

while

$ \displaystyle\lim_{m \to \infty} \log(m)=\infty $?

Comment: Your question is unclear - the title doesn't agree with the body of the question. The proof you have given shows that $(m+1)/m < \log(m)$ for all sufficiently large $m$. If that's what you need that's fine. But $(m+1)/m < \log(m)$ is false for small $m$, e.g., $m  = 1$.

Comment: $(m+1)/m \le 2$ for all $m$ while $\log m  > 2$ for $m>e^2$.

Comment: Yes, that was all I needed. I was simply concerned about using those limits as the only steps in the proof. I changed the title.

Comment: Ok. Then yes, that would be an overkill, but it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach this question is to look at $a_m=\frac{m+1}{m}\frac{1}{\log(m)}$. $a_m\to 0$ as $m\to\infty$, so there exists some $m_0$ s.t for every $m\geq m_0$, $a_m<1$. Therefore for every $m\geq m_0$, $\frac{m+1}{m}\frac{1}{\log(m)}<1$, multiplying by $\log(m)$ gives the desired result. Notice that as the comments suggest, this is only true from a  certain point (for example, not true for $m=1$). My proof shows the inequality does hold when $m\gg 0$, but doesn't find which $m$ explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{m+1}{m}=1+\frac{1}{m}\le2 ~~~\text{for}~~~m\ge 1$$

$$2<\ln m ~~~\text{for}~~~m\ge 8$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{m+1}{m}\le2<\ln m ~~~\text{for}~~~m\ge 8$$